# Issue combining two data sets based on date and daily energy using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

hopefully a basic one for most.

I have created two datasets using random data one for days of the year and other for energy per day:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
np.random.seed(2)
start2018 = pd.datetime(2018, 1, 1)
end2018 = pd.datetime(2018, 12, 31)
dates2018 = pd.date_range(start2018, end2018, freq='d')
synEne2018 = np.random.normal(loc=66.883795, scale=5.448145, size=365)
syn2018data = pd.DataFrame({'Date': [dates2018], 'Total Daily Energy': [synEne2018]})
syn2018data
```

When I run this code I was hoping to get the daily energy for each date on separate rows. However, what I get is one row similar to below:
Date    Total Daily Energy
0   DatetimeIndex(['2018-01-01', '2018-01-02', '20...   [64.61323781744713, 66.57724516658102, 55.2454...

Can someone suggest the edit to get this to display as described above..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the square brackets around dates2018 and synEne2018. You are making them nested list by putting square brackets around them. Just leave them alone as it is and you should be good to go.

```
syn2018data = pd.DataFrame({'Date': dates2018, 'Total Daily Energy': synEne2018})
```

Prints:

```
          Date  Total Daily Energy
0   2018-01-01           64.613238
1   2018-01-02           66.577245
2   2018-01-03           55.245489
3   2018-01-04           75.820228
4   2018-01-05           57.112898
..         ...                 ...
360 2018-12-27           73.685533
361 2018-12-28           60.096896
362 2018-12-29           65.973035
363 2018-12-30           63.742335
364 2018-12-31           69.150342

[365 rows x 2 columns]
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you. I knew it was something minor thanks for spotting. I will accept answer when the time limit is up.